# Loading a partial view in ASP.NET MVC using javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, partial-views

I have about 15 partial views that I need to display based upon user's menu tab selection. Basically I have these 15 menu tabs on the side and based on user click for these tabs, I will be displaying the content for that tab on the page.

Also I am using Knockout here.

So I have these 15 Knockout observables (`self.tab_A(), self.tab_B(), ...self.tab_N()`) populated when the page first loads.

The code I have is something like this. 
Here is the view.

```
<ul id="tabs">
    <li>
        <a data-bind="click: function(){ $root.ShowHideDiv(tab_A.id); }" style="cursor: pointer;">
           Tab A
        </a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a data-bind="click: function(){ $root.ShowHideDiv(tab_B.id); }" style="cursor: pointer;">
         Tab B
        </a>
    </li>
    ...
    ...
</ul>
```

The partial views are pre-loaded but hidden from from user's view.

```
<ul>
    <li id="tab_A" style="display: none" class="hiddenDivs">
        @{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Claims/FroiReport/_Insurer.cshtml");}
    </li>

    <li id="tab_B" style="display: none" class="hiddenDivs">
        @{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Claims/FroiReport/_Insurer.cshtml");}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Displaying div using script on click event.

```
 self.ShowHideDiv = function (tabToShow) {
        console.log(tabToShow);
        $('.hiddenDivs').html('');
        $('#' + tabToShow).show();
    };
```

Now, the problem is that the UI using this code is working fine for 3-4 views but the design is breaking for the remaining views possibly because there are too many divs which are being hidden (I am not sure here).

So, I was looking into other options where I will load the specific view at run-time only. When user clicks on a tab, get the partial view and load it.

Hence, I tried something like this:

```
self.ShowHideDiv = function (tabToShow) {
    $('.hiddenDivs').html('');
    var view = getValueFromDict(dict, tabToShow); //gets the needed view from a dictionary in "~/Views/Products/CoolProducts/_ItemOne.cshtml" format
    $('.hiddenDivs').load('/Claims/ReturnPartialView/?partialViewName=' + view);
};
```

But this doesn't work since I do not have any Action/Controller associated with these views, I am unable to load the view directly using javascript/jquery.

Another option I have tried is creating a controller that returns a partial view.

```
public ActionResult ReturnPartialView(string partialViewName)
        {
            return PartialView(partialViewName);
        }
```

and calling it like this:

```
self.ShowHideDiv = function (tabToShow) {
    $('.hiddenDivs').html('');
    var view = getValueFromDict(dict, tabToShow);
    $('.hiddenDivs').load('/MyController/ReturnPartialView/?partialViewName=' + view);
}
```

Now this loads the view that I need but the KnockOut observable associated with the view is coming as null doing this.

I heard that KO templates can be used for my scenario but have not yet tried KO templates to solve this (which I am going to look into next). I would like to see if anyone has solution to my problem without using the KO templates.

Thanks much for your patience to trying to understand this.

Comment: You have to hit controller through ajax get/post method and then return a partial view.

Comment: So if there is no Action that is calling this View then I can not load it using javascript/ajax?

Comment: You have to hit action of controller ..

Comment: Other option is to load the partialview on page load, and then hide it using CSS. Then you can show or many copies of the hidden partialview through jquery. If you dont want to take this route, then you have to hit the action and return the partialview.

Comment: @ramiramilu he may need to change the content of partial view after loading. That is why he is hitting the action by ajax/javascript.

Comment: @MuhammadAshikuzzaman you might be right, but OP doesn't want to hit the controller/action. so I gave just another option by hiding the partialview.

Comment: @ramiramilu Actually I was loading the partial view and hiding it using css as you suggested in the first place, but since I have many views, it is breaking my design. So I was thinking if I could load view only when needed. I will look into creating an Action to load the partial view but I am not sure if this will perform well with my Knockout objects. So far the objects are becoming null when I am loading the view through Action. Maybe I will have to ask another question for this case now :)

Comment: @pso do you want to load it at the first time or after a certain time or when some button are clicked?

Comment: @MuhammadAshikuzzaman please refer to my prev comment.

Comment: Use knockout templates or any template engine to create your partial views and bind them together. ASP.net actions and views are not quite enough to create Single Page App's as they are MVC and what you are trying to do is MVVM.

Comment: @pso Show us some sample code, so that I can propose a working solution.

Comment: @ramiramilu I will edit the question with some code to display what I am doing. Thanks!~

Comment: Thanks @HastaPasta. I will look for a solution using KO templates as well.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with jQuery in two steps.First from your view hit the desired controller action after the dom is ready or when an event is occurred. I have call controller  here after the dom is ready. You can hit action get or post method as you wish. 

Here in $.ajax I have used ( **async: false** ) so that the statement now I am calling has to be completed before the next statement in the function can be executed.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () { 
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Controller/ActionNAme',
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            data: { ModelField: value},
            success: function (result) {
                $("#your_desired_div_id").html(result);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is the action. The action return a view model as result to ajax.post function and in the ajax post function your your_desired_div_id content is changed with the partial view's contents.

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ActionNAme  (ModelName ModelField)
        {
            var dBList= (from myTable in db.tableModel where myTable .column == ModelField.column  select  myTable).ToList();
                 return PartialView("_PartialView", dBList) 

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Same has been explained here..

https://cmatskas.com/update-an-mvc-partial-view-with-ajax/

Comment: @Arasu, I looked at the link you provided but it is not the same scenario. The link is showing example for a view which is called through an Action from the controller unlike my case.

Comment: @pso Okay. As like Muhammed mentioned in comment, you have to hit controller action from jquery/ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a controller action which returns the partial view.

```
public ActionResult MyPartialView()
    {
        return PartialView("_MyPartialView", new MyPartialViewModel());
    }
```

You can call this controller method from javascript. Make sure the partial view exists in Views folder under the folder which matches your controller name.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks @Amanvir but I am looking for a way to load it without hitting the Controller/Action.